# Django: My object's list attribute not saving inside of a function

Tags: python, django, list, class, attributes

Newbie to Django here.
So I made a model with an attribute being a list. Then I made an instance of it. Then I have a function that has a for loop that appends to the "class list" attribute of the object. This is not permanently saving the list data to the attribute of the object (isn't that the whole point of model objects?). I am very confused on how to do that.

```
class Mymodel:
   class_list = []

my_object = Mymodel()
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

def myFunction():
   for value in values:
      my_object.class_list.append(value)

   return something_unrelated
```

So in my_object, I want new values saved in its class_list attribute. I don't want the function to return the class_list. I want Django to save the attributes in its database. If I insert print statements before and after the for loop (see below), I get exactly what I would expect.

```
def myFunction():
   print(my_object.class_list)
   for value in values:
      my_object.class_list.append(value)
   print(my_object.class_list)

   return something_unrelated
```

In the consul I will see

```
[]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

But if I `print(my_object.class_list)` afterward, it will print `[]`
So how do I get Django to save my object info? What am I missing or am I doing something completely wrong here?

***Edit***
I think the thing I was looking for was the `save()` function, but I just tried using it on my_object ie

```
def myFunction():
   print(my_object.class_list)
   for value in values:
      my_object.class_list.append(value)
   print(my_object.class_list)
   my_object.save()

   return something_unrelated
```

But if I call MyFunction again, the list is still empty(the first print statement still returns an empty string). I am still not sure how to save it permanently to the database.

Comment: I am still not clear what you are trying to achieve, why are you looping. maybe shed more light and we just might see a better approach than the for-loop

Comment: A few days ago I saw a wonderful comment describing this problem, although I cannot find it now I will put it in my own words. Each HTTP request is independent of each other and the server should not be expected to have knowledge of some previous request. You should have a mindset that there will be multiple users accessing your website and you might be concurrently running your website on more than one server.

Comment: Considering all this, saving data as you try to do (globally) is a bad idea. (I assume you work in development. The thing that is happening is that each request is served by a different thread, none of which have a knowledge of what the other does) You need to save data to the **database**. You just naming a class `Mymodel` does **not** make it a model in Django, also a model only stores data into the db using some model fields and not some builtin python datatype. On how to use models see [Models (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your object to the database, you need to use the save method.

Try `my_object.save()` after you've altered it.

Comment: Of course, this is only if your model is registered in the models.py file and you've migrated it to your database. After that, you can take advantage of Django's ORM.